# How can I get Nodejs twitter-passport behind proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, passport-twitter

I'm testing twitter auth using passport-twitter's nodejs module. I already created my Twitter app and configured everything like especified by tutorials. The problem is that i'm behind a corporative proxy and as far as i know, node doesn't have any global proxy configuration and do not respect system proxy configuration. This is the output i get when i try to authenticate using twitter-passport:

> InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token
>       at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:390:13)
>       at /home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:244:40
>       at /home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:543:17
>       at ClientRequest. (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:421:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:265:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
>       at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)

So far, i have tried to set a global tunnel using this:

```
var globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel');
globalTunnel.initialize({
  host: 'proxy.example.com',
  port: 8080
});
```

In this case, all I get is this message:

> TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:54:11)
>       at exports.request (http.js:31:10)
>       at TunnelingAgent.http.request (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/http-proxy.js:36:15)
>       at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:116:25)
>       at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:188:41)
>       at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/tunnel/lib/tunnel.js:80:8)
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:139:16)
>       at exports.request (http.js:31:10)
>       at Object.http.request (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/http-proxy.js:36:15)
>       at Object.globalTunnel._defaultedAgentRequest (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/global-tunnel/index.js:211:38)
>       at Object.exports.request (https.js:173:15)
>       at Object.globalTunnel._defaultedAgentRequest (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/global-tunnel/index.js:211:38)
>       at exports.OAuth._createClient (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:256:20)
>       at exports.OAuth._performSecureRequest (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:371:19)
>       at exports.OAuth.getOAuthRequestToken (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:542:8)
>       at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (/home/droid/WebstormProjects/passport-social-master/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:242:21)

I tried too the semi-global proxy(http://blog.shaunxu.me/archive/2013/09/05/semi-global-proxy-setting-for-node.js.aspx) by Shaun Xu. I imported the modified require.js everywhere but nothing is working. So i'm getting without options...

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem** :

An old dependence in global-tunnel. see [global-tunnel Issue #13](https://github.com/SalesforceEng/global-tunnel/issues/13)

Quick solution : updating node-tunnel dependency to 0.0.4 does not seems to work at the end since using it will redirect all requests to internet proxy vs only authentication requests.

---

It's an 'old' post but if someone has a similar problem:

**Use case** :

- Server is behind an internet proxy
- Server access local resources via http/https, for example an elasticsearch server that must not be requested via proxy
- You are using passportJs with Authentication module witch requires an external token validation, for exemple google on https://accounts.google.com

**Problem** :

- By default NodeJs does not take into account any system proxy setting
- Company proxy does not forward internal request via internet proxy (eg: if  proxy is set, all requests are going to internet proxy, not anymore in intranet or localhost)

**Solution not working** :

Setting system env HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY *does not works* for 2 reasons:

- NodeJs ignore them
- Proxy is set for all requests, and you want only one specific request to go through proxy

Using a global proxy (global-tunnel or similar) will fails because they redirect all requests adding their own Agent (request.options.agent) and thus will forward all your traffic to your proxy. Not desired.

**A Solution** :

Use a similar code as global-tunnel, adding a whitelist to proxy only some hostnames.

I ve implemented and tested this solution with success : see https://github.com/bloublou2014/httpx-proxy-agent-config

Usage example :

```
var proxy = require('httpx-proxy-agent-config');

proxy.install({
http_proxy: 'http://yourProxy:3128',
https_proxy: 'http://yourHttpsProxy:3218',
// example for passportjs Google OAuth2 + Google+
whitelist: ['www.google.com','accounts.google.com', '173.194.66.95', '74.125.192.95', '209.85.201.95', 'www.googleapis.com']
});

// try to access a page via http request :
var http = require('http');
http.get('http://www.google.com', function (response) { 
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (d) {
        body += d;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body=", body);
    });
});

// try to access a page via https request
var https = require('https');
https.get('https://www.google.com', function (response) {   
    var body = '';
    response.on('data', function (d) {
        body += d;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body=", body);
    });
});
```